# "Много рыбы плавает" - why not "плавают"?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова

I came across this sentence

> В этой реке много рыбы плавает

I understand that after много you need the genitive plural of a noun, and рыбы is the genitive plural of рыба so why isn't it "...рыбы плавают"?

Comment: In this case, it's a genitive singular "рыбы", so it's "плавает". "В этой реке много рыб плавает" would be a more challenging case.

Comment: You're right! Assuming that the sentence is grammatically correct - why is it in genitive singular?

Comment: This is not duplicate of the linked question because there they use plural unlike this one.

Comment: Fish here works as uncountable noun. Like in English "there is a lot of fish in this lake" (not "fishes")